# How to add a changeHandler() to my program

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, jslider, changelistener

Please, I tried to add a changeHandler event but I don't think I got it right. I am looking at the following statements..

```
pickNum.addChangeListener(new ChangeHandler());

 @Override
 public void stateChanged(changeEvent e)
 {
   JSlider s = (JSlider)e.getSource();
   index = s.getValue();
 }
```

Is there something I could have done better because because, it's not working..

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Slider extends JFrame{

public static int index;
JSlider pickNum = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL,0,30,5);
public Slider()
{
 super("Slider");
 this.pack();
 this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

 pickNum.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
 pickNum.setMinorTickSpacing(1);
 pickNum.setPaintTicks(true);
 pickNum.setPaintLabels(true);
 pickNum.addChangeListener(new ChangeHandler());

 @Override
 public void stateChanged(changeEvent e)
 {
   JSlider s = (JSlider)e.getSource();
   index = s.getValue();
 }

 getPointedValue();
 this.add(pickNum);
 this.setVisible(true);

}

public final int getPointedValue()
{
    int value;
    value = pickNum.getValue();
    return value;
}


     public static void main(String[] args) {

    Slider frame = new Slider();
    System.out.println("value is :"+Slider.index);
   }

 }

[/CODE]
```

Comment: "Not working" is _never_ a sufficient problem description. What do you expect should happen, and what's actually happening?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3):

What is your ChangeHandler? You haven't posted that code

Here is an example of using a change listener

```
JSlider s = new JSlider();
s.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
   public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
      System.out.println("Changed: " + e);
   }
});
```

Comment: Hello guys,
sorry, I have the code now in full. here is the changeHandler method.
  [CODE]
     
        JSlider pickNum = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL,0,30,5);
        public Slider()
        {
         super("Slider");
         
          
          pickNum.addChangeListener(new ChangeHandler());

           @Override
           public void stateChanged(changeEvent e)
           {
             JSlider s = (JSlider)e.getSource();
             index = s.getValue();
           }
       
       }

Answer (score 2):

What is the implementation of your `ChangeHandler`? You don't really need an separate file for it, the ChangeListener interface only has one method so you can quickly provide an implementation while declaring it inline

```
pickNum.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {    
    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0) {
        JSlider s = (JSlider) arg0.getSource();
        index = s.getValue();   
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

What is that `ChangeHandler` class you are talking about ? It is not part of the JDK. Did you mix up the `ChangeHandler` class from GWT with the `ChangeListener` from the JDK ?

Further, I would suggest you take a look at the [Swing slider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html) for sample code working with sliders. For example a nice sample implementation of such a `ChangeListener` attached to the slider

```
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
    JSlider source = (JSlider)e.getSource();
    if (!source.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
        int fps = (int)source.getValue();
        if (fps == 0) {
            if (!frozen) stopAnimation();
        } else {
            delay = 1000 / fps;
            timer.setDelay(delay);
            timer.setInitialDelay(delay * 10);
            if (frozen) startAnimation();
        }
    }
}
```

Note the `getValueIsAdjusting()` call which you misses in your code snippet